# how to open a popup automatically when website opens in laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to show text and image with close button as given in the image below in the popup automatically when the website open in laravel 5.6.
I couldn't found the solution.

[image: image popup sample]

Comment: This is not laravel question. It is all about jquery and html. laravel or its version has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Put this element in div and  set `display:none;` as it style.
For example

`<div id="yourElementID" style="display:none;">
    <img src="img.jpg"><p>text</p>
 </div>`

For displaying it on load :
You should use Javascript/jQuery for it.
Either pure JS

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('yourElementID').style.display = "block";
};
</script>
```

or with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#yourElementId').show();
});
```

If you want it to wait little bit before showing use timeout.
And well If you want it to have close button aswell, then you can put some `img` or `a` element there and set attribute `onClick="$(this).hide();"` <- If you are using jQuery

Comment: where can i add image and text here

Comment: Put your image and text in a DIV as I said before, for example `<div id="yourElementID" style="display:none;"><img src="img.jpg"><p>text</p></div>` I'm not going to create it for you, with the information I already gave you you should be able to create your popup. And well If you want it to have close button aswell, then you can put some `img` or `a` element there and set attribute `onClick="$(this).hide();"` <- If you are using jQuery